# UITableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and UIImageView issue?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I'm loading asynchronously images into UITableView and each row has different image. the problem is when i scroll the UITableView the previous images are loaded again in the new rows and after a while these images are changed to the correct ones (this problem is gone when i removed **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** but it reduces the performance)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellFriends" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];  
        nibObjects = nil;
     } 

     UIImageView *avatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
     UILabel *city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

     EntryProfile *entryForRow = [entriesProfileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    avatar.image = nil;

     NSString *strLinkImage = [entryForRow.apiAvatarPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:avatar,strLinkImage,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row], nil];
     NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addPhotoWithImageView:) object:args];
     [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
     [operation release];

     // Set the name of the user
     name.text = entryForRow.name;

     return cell;
}

// Method 
- (void)addPhotoWithImageView:(NSArray *)args
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[args objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strLinkImage = (NSString *)[args objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *index = (NSString *)[args objectAtIndex:2];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com%@",strLinkImage]]];
    UIImage *imageField = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    if (imageData) {
        [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:imageField waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    [imageField release];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are people still facing this issue, I see the answers above do not really help.

2 steps to take:

- You need to "cancel" the asynchronous request that is ongoing for the image view and then set a new image asynchronously with a placeholder image till the async request goes through
- Ideally, do not send your async request while the user is scrolling through 
  (tableview/scrollview is decelerating) - try to avoid making new requests and just set the placeholder in such cases (unless you have a way of confidently knowing that the request was done before and hence it is likely that the image is found in the local disk cache for the image url)

The above 2 steps will keep your functionality as intended and give you good performance too.

Comment: @meronix: setting the item to nil or to a placeholder might not work well in case the asynchronous loading initiated before happens *after* you load the new placeholder (it can even happen that the new request happens before the old one and you then see the wrong image for the cell). No guarantee of when the async requests complete and in what order - so the only way out is to cancel the old requests.
Check out AFNetworking for a good library that allows you to set an image asynchronously with a placeholder, and also cancel such requests (UIImage+AFNetworking.h)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem, easily solved.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation, you can include code like this:

```
if (!tableView.decellerating) {
    // set avatar.image to its correct UIImage value how ever you like, 
    // in the background if necessary
} else {
    // table is scrolling...
    avatar.image = nil;
}
```

And then implement this method in your view controller:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
    [visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)obj;
        UIImageView *avatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        avatar.image = ...; // Do what you need to do to set the image in the cell
    }];
}
```

You will also need to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to the list of protocols your view controller adopts.

The idea here is that as long as the table view is moving, don't bother loading the images. Your performance will skyrocket.

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath,
before you call:

```
 NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addPhotoWithImageView:) object:args];
```

force yourCell imageView.image to nil

```
imageView.image = nil;
```

this way you clean the contents image of old cell, then it will be redraw with right image when it's loaded...

**EDIT**

maybe nil doesn't works...

try a placeHolder image, a real png file (with a color, for test, then it may be a transparent file...)

Comment: i see you set overtime the image of cell.tag=100, not the current cell... why? do you need some special code and not normal UITableView behavior? in this case explain what your needs are...

Comment: it's just a tag that refer to UIImageView

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your own UItableViewCell and set the all your cell properties to nil in the PrepareForReuse method.

I would also recomend you to take a look at this project in order to load asynchronously remote images:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

I used it with great success in different projects.

Comment: You mean make a loop for each subview in UITableViewCell and set them to nil?

Comment: No. Just implement your own UItableViewCell class instead of direcly create your UItableViewCell from cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then implement PrepareForReuse

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue the other day and the way I solved it was the following ( I didn't notice any performance reduction ).

```
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (cell == nil) {
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

// rest of the code

}
```

So basically invoke the dequeue inside the if.

Comment: This is actually wrong. What if there are no reusable cells to dequeue? Then your `cell` variable is nil. The original poster's code was correct, at least as it relates to this particular nuance.

Comment: You know what... I take it back. This will work IF you register a class for the reuse identifier by calling `registerNib:forCellReuseIndentifier:`. But without that, this alone won't work right all the time.